# CAEmitterLayer (ios5) vs CCParticleSystem (cocos2d) Performance

Tags: performance, uikit, cocos2d-iphone, particle-system

I am to create an app with lots and lots of particle effects and I was planning to use cocos2d framework. But just recently, I came to know that particle systems can be created in ios5.

I like to know how the UIKit particle system performs when compared to cocos2d particle system.

Anyone tried and tested?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? After all, you can only compare the performance of the two if you use the exact same particle effect.

Comment: Would be interested to hear your findings @saiy2k.

Comment: With the help of (http://www.raywenderlich.com/6063/uikit-particle-systems-in-ios-5-tutorial), I created a simple particle system using CAEmitterLayer... But now, I dont know how to calculate the FPS in CoreAnimation. Without FPS calculation performance comparison cant be done... Any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 4):

You can check out Dazzle (at https://github.com/lichtschlag/Dazzle), a test app I wrote to test the new iOS 5 particle effect APIs. Frame rates can get low (20 fps) if you spawn to many objects. I do not know how Cocos compares to that, but here is how to monitor the fps:

1. Build your app using the 'Profile' option, so that Instruments attaches to it.
2. Select 'Core Animation' Instrument (in the Graphics category). You will need an actual device for that.
3. Navigate to your particle code, Instruments will display the fps.

If you need to profile opengl code, use the appropriate instrument.